# How to put data to firebase realtime database in nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, nuxt.js

I have this data:

```
const data = {
title: this.title,
subtitle: this.subtitle,
image: imageUrl
}
```

I've tried:

```
this.$fire.database.ref('hero_page').put(data)
```

but I'm getting errors.

I want my databse to look like this:

```
hero_page:
  title: test_title,
  subtitle: test_subtitle,
  image: test_url_of_image
}
```

Comment: `I'm getting errors`, which are?

Comment: put is not a function @kissu

Comment: That sounds correct. Are you looking for `set`? Also see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#write_data